# Searching a list C#

Tags: c#, sql, list, search, console

Hope all is well.

I am struggling with a simple problem here. I am trying to create a console app that allows you to search for words in a list (by one or more characters ie u = user, user group).

I can't seem to get past this error:
Error   CS0305  Using the generic type 'List' requires 1 type arguments  wordSearch  c:\Projects\wordSearch\wordSearch\Program.cs    36  Active

Please find my code below..... Any help is welcome Thank you in advance.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace wordSearch
{


public class MyList<T> { }
public class TestList<T> { }

class MyList
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string searchKeyword = "o";

        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("User");
        items.Add("User Groups");
        items.Add("User Activity Log");
        items.Add("Report Designer");
        items.Add("Report Activity Log");



        List<string> searchResults = items.FindAll(u => 
         u.Contains(searchKeyword));


            Console.WriteLine("Please type in the first letter of item you 
            are looking for:");
            Console.ReadLine();

        foreach (var result in System.Collections.Generic.List.Where(u => 
         u.IndexOf(mySearchString) == 0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User, User Groups, User Activity Log");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
       foreach (var result in List.Where(r => r.IndexOf(mySearchString) == 
        0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Report Desinger, Report Activity Log");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you think `List.Where(...)` is doing here?

Comment: You use variable `mySearchString`, but not define it. Please, fix it in code exaple.

Comment: all the "List.Where" bits need to be items.Where .... you're using YOUR list, it has the data

Answer (score 3):

There are *two* issues with your code:

1. You have to *save* user's input ("...the first letter user is looking for..."), e.g. in `mySearchString` which you've already used as filter.
2. You have to query and scan `items` *instance*, not `System.Collections.Generic.ListList` *type*:

You can put it like this:

```
  ...

  Console.WriteLine("Please type in the first letter of item you are looking for:");

  //DONE: user input saved
  string mySearchString = Console.ReadLine();

  //DONE: we scan items, not List 
  foreach (var result in items.Where(u => u.IndexOf(mySearchString) == 0)) {
      Console.WriteLine("User, User Groups, User Activity Log");
      Console.ReadKey();
  }

  // DONE: we scan items not List
  foreach (var result in items.Where(r => r.IndexOf(mySearchString) == 0)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Report Desinger, Report Activity Log");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }

  ...
```

**Edit**: It seems that the actual request is to query list in a *loop*, `foreach` not copy-pasting, something  like this:

```
public static void Main() {
  List<string> items = new List<string>() {
    "User",
    "User Groups",
    "User Activity Log",
    "Report Designer",
    "Report Activity Log",
  }

  while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please type in the first letter of item you are looking for:");
    Console.WriteLine("Prease press enter (i.e. type an empty string) to quit"); 

    string mySearchString = Console.ReadLine();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySearchString)) 
      break;

    foreach (var item in items.Where(r => r.IndexOf(mySearchString) == 0))
      Console.WriteLine(item);

    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry and everyone for all the constructive crit and thought provoking questions.